# Python yield statement issue in recursive function?

Tags: python, algorithm, yield

Now, I learn to how to use `yield` in python program. so I want to implement `word permutation` in python.

```
def permuteArr(arr, index=0):
    '''(list, int) -> list

    Get all the permutation of the elements in list.
    >>> arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    >>> for val in permuteArr(arr):
            print val
    '''
    if index == len(arr):
        yield arr
    else:
        for idx in range(index, len(arr)):
            arr[idx], arr[index] = arr[index], arr[idx]
            for val in permuteArr(arr, idx+1):
                yield val
            arr[idx], arr[index] = arr[index], arr[idx]

if '__name__' == '__main__':
    arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    for val in permuteArr(arr, 0):
        print val
```

However, I run it in python shell under window, the results are not correct. There are only four results.

```
>>> for v in permuteArr(['a', 'b', 'c']):
    print v

['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'c', 'b']
['b', 'a', 'c']
['c', 'b', 'a']
```

Is anything wrong when I use yield or in my program?

Comment: Why do you want to do this recursively? It seems very awkward

Comment: @PatrickCollins recursion is the natural approach to a problem like this, since the number of permutations grows as N! and an iterative approach is hard to reason out (you'd like to be able to write N nested loops, but you don't know N ahead of time).

That said, this functionality is already implemented as `itertools.permutations`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In loop `for val in permuteArr(arr, idx+1):` replace `idx + 1` on `index + 1`